# How do i track an order using laravel lumen?

Tags: laravel, api, postman, lumen

I'm integrating APIs that will be connected to an E-Commerce platform. I'm supposed to add an option to track orders, how do I do that?

Also, there's no frontend yet so I'm using postman to test all the API's.

the orders go through different locations on their way to the buyer, and I'd like the customer to now at which station their item is

Comment: Okay what do you mean by track orders? What and when needs to be tracked. What is the definition of tracking orders?

solutions could be: push notifications, simple order table where you put a reference in, event listeners what is it that you actually need to do.

Comment: I want the customer to put in the system generated tracking number and then have a table/view that indicates which station the item is at the moment

Comment: push notifications do sound like something I'll need to add eventually but not that urgent at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan make:observer OrderObserver
```

then something in the observer like this:

```php
    /**
     * Handles the correct fields when updating
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    public function updating(User $user)
    {
        if($order->isDirty('some_column_you_use_to_change_status')) {
              $someStatusTable = SomeStatusTable::where('track_id', $order->track_id)->first();
          $someStatusTable->status = "whateverYOUwant";
        }
    }
```

I really don't know your logic but i think this could be something.

by the wat ->isDirty() watches if columns were changed.

you can also get the $order->getOriginal(('some_column_you_use_to_change_status')

I use this for example history of a Model to register history or even set new versions in my models